# R find last weekday of month

Tags: r, date

How do I find the last weekday (e.g., Wednesday) of the month using R?  In the code below, I calculate the month, day of the month, week of the month, and weekday.  There are 5 Wednesdays in January 2014, but only 4 Wednesdays in February 2014, so I cannot use max(week of the month) as a filter.  Any help is appreciated although I prefer to use the base R functions.

```
DF <- data.frame(DATE = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), "day"))

DF$MONTH         <- as.numeric(format(DF$DATE, "%m"))
DF$DAY_OF_MONTH  <- as.numeric(format(DF$DATE, "%d"))
DF$WEEK_OF_MONTH <- ceiling(as.numeric(format(DF$DATE, "%d")) / 7)
DF$WEEKDAY       <- format(DF$DATE, "%A")

DF
```

Comment: The goal is to create a new column that, for each day/row, gives the last weekday of that month?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
DF$last_weekday_o_month <- ave( 
  weekdays(DF$DATE), 
  months(DF$DATE), 
  FUN = function(x) tail(x[ !(x %in% c("Saturday","Sunday")) ], 1) 
)
```

To find the particular date that is the last weekday....

```
DF$last_weekdaydate_o_month <- ave( 
  DF$DATE, 
  months(DF$DATE), 
  FUN = function(x) tail(x[ !(weekdays(x) %in% c("Saturday","Sunday")) ], 1) 
)
```

the result looks like...

```
          DATE last_weekday_o_month last_weekdaydate_o_month
1   2014-01-01               Friday               2014-01-31
2   2014-01-02               Friday               2014-01-31
3   2014-01-03               Friday               2014-01-31
4   2014-01-04               Friday               2014-01-31
5   2014-01-05               Friday               2014-01-31
6   2014-01-06               Friday               2014-01-31
...
360 2014-12-26            Wednesday               2014-12-31
361 2014-12-27            Wednesday               2014-12-31
362 2014-12-28            Wednesday               2014-12-31
363 2014-12-29            Wednesday               2014-12-31
364 2014-12-30            Wednesday               2014-12-31
365 2014-12-31            Wednesday               2014-12-31
```

If you did this first, of course you could compute `last_weekday_o_month` as `weekdays(last_weekdaydate_o_month)`.

---

With a couple packages, this can be done more elegantly/readably, as suggested by @RichardScriven:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, 
  last_weekdaydate_o_month := last(DATE[!chron::is.weekend(DATE)])
, by = month(DATE)]
```

which gives

```
           DATE last_weekdaydate_o_month
  1: 2014-01-01               2014-01-31
  2: 2014-01-02               2014-01-31
  3: 2014-01-03               2014-01-31
  4: 2014-01-04               2014-01-31
  5: 2014-01-05               2014-01-31
 ---                                    
361: 2014-12-27               2014-12-31
362: 2014-12-28               2014-12-31
363: 2014-12-29               2014-12-31
364: 2014-12-30               2014-12-31
365: 2014-12-31               2014-12-31
```

Comment: I am trying to find the last specific weekday, for example, the last Wednesday of the month.  Maybe I could modify your code to say FUN = function(x) tail(x[ ! (x %in% c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday").

Comment: @user1491868 I've updated the answer; yeah, it's something like that.

Comment: `setDT(DF)[, last(DATE[!chron::is.weekend(DATE)]), by = month(DATE)]` might be useful

Answer (score 6):

Here is a method using `dplyr`.  Essentially you group by the month, filter out the 'weekend' days and return the weekday of the last (i.e. max) day.

```
library(dplyr)

DF <- data.frame(DATE = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), "day"))

DF %>%
  mutate(month = months(DATE), weekday = weekdays(DATE)) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  filter(!weekday %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")) %>%
  summarise(last_weekday = weekdays(max(DATE))) 

Source: local data frame [12 x 2]

       month        last_weekday
1      April           Wednesday
2     August              Friday
3   December           Wednesday
4   February              Friday
5    January              Friday
6       July            Thursday
7       June              Monday
8      March              Monday
9        May              Friday
10  November              Friday
11   October              Friday
12 September             Tuesday
```

Comment: @Frank, ah, I just had it loaded already so I added it in thinking I used it.  It isn't necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
x <- seq(as.Date("2007-12-31"), by="1 day", length.out=(Sys.Date() - as.Date("2007-12-31")))
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(date=x, year=year(x), month=month(x))
df[,"weekday"] <- weekdays(df[,"date"])
df<- df[! df[,"weekday"] %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"),]
df <- ddply(df, .(year, month), summarize, last=max(date))
```