# how to detect last nth workdays of a month using R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable in my data.table based on a date column by using the rule below.

**Rule**: if the "date" is one of the last 3 workdays (it can be any day from Monday to Friday) of a month then code it as "1"; otherwise code it as "0".

Below is an example how I need to see the result. The 3rd column includes the explanation for coding.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683981/how-to-flag-last-friday-or-last-day-or-month?rq=1) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088424/r-find-last-weekday-of-month?rq=1) are pretty good starts along the `weekdays` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2017/01/01"), as.Date("2017/12/31"), "days"))
df$day <- weekdays(x = df$date)
df$month <- months(x = df$date)

true_flags <- df %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  filter(day!='Sunday' & day!='Saturday') %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  top_n(wt = date,n = 3) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  transmute(date=date,flag=T)

df %>% left_join(y=true_flags,by = 'date')
```