# Sequence of last observation of months in a series of dates in R

Tags: r

If I have a range of business day dates from `2010-01-04` to `2014-12-31`, how do I create a vector of dates containing the last date for each month in my data?

I've looked through zoo and lubridate packages but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R find last weekday of month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088424/r-find-last-weekday-of-month)

Comment: With a reproducible example and its desired output, you might get closer to the answer you want.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want. Please show the answer you expect for the input shown.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a two-step process to get the job done:

1. Use `lubridate::ceiling_date` to get the first day of next month
2. We generate a sequence "by month" and subtract 1 day

---

```
# generage some random dates
set.seed(123)
mydates <- sample(seq(from = as.Date("2017-01-01"), 
                      to   = as.Date("2018-12-31"), by="day"), 10)

# generate requested sequence
d1 <- lubridate::ceiling_date(min(mydates), "month")
d2 <- lubridate::ceiling_date(max(mydates), "month")

result <- seq(from=d1, to=d2, by="month") - 1
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the last date of the month from my given data set.

Comment: @bloodynri If you gave an example dataset for us to work with we would be able to give you a solution that works for a given dataset

Comment: Updated answer to provide some data and generalize my approach.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear whether you want all end of months for the two dates plus all months between them or just for the two dates but below we show both.

**1)** Here is a one-liner using the `yearmon` class and gives all end of months for the from the first date to the second date.  Convert each input character string to `yearmon` class, create a sequence of them and convert to `Date` class using `frac` equals 1 (which means last day of month).

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(seq(as.yearmon("2010-01-04"), as.yearmon("2014-12-31"), 1/12), frac = 1)
```

giving:

```
[1] "2010-01-31" "2010-02-28" "2010-03-31" "2010-04-30" "2010-05-31"
[6] "2010-06-30" "2010-07-31" "2010-08-31" "2010-09-30" "2010-10-31"
[11] "2010-11-30" "2010-12-31" "2011-01-31" "2011-02-28" "2011-03-31"
[16] "2011-04-30" "2011-05-31" "2011-06-30" "2011-07-31" "2011-08-31"
[21] "2011-09-30" "2011-10-31" "2011-11-30" "2011-12-31" "2012-01-31"
[26] "2012-02-29" "2012-03-31" "2012-04-30" "2012-05-31" "2012-06-30"
[31] "2012-07-31" "2012-08-31" "2012-09-30" "2012-10-31" "2012-11-30"
[36] "2012-12-31" "2013-01-31" "2013-02-28" "2013-03-31" "2013-04-30"
[41] "2013-05-31" "2013-06-30" "2013-07-31" "2013-08-31" "2013-09-30"
[46] "2013-10-31" "2013-11-30" "2013-12-31" "2014-01-31" "2014-02-28"
[51] "2014-03-31" "2014-04-30" "2014-05-31" "2014-06-30" "2014-07-31"
[56] "2014-08-31" "2014-09-30" "2014-10-31" "2014-11-30" "2014-12-31"
```

**2)** or if you mean you just want the corresponding end of month for each input date then here is a one-liner for that:

```
library(zoo)

x <- c("2010-01-04", "2014-12-31") # input data
as.Date(as.yearmon(x), frac = 1)
```

giving:

```
[1] "2010-01-31" "2014-12-31"
```

**2a)** To do this without any packages first define a first of month function and then apply it twice as shown.

```
fom <- function(x) as.Date(cut(as.Date(x), "month"))
fom(fom(x) + 31) - 1
```

giving:

```
[1] "2010-01-31" "2014-12-31"
```

Comment: The `+31` with the recursive `fom()` in 2a is clever!  I had thought about a `+31` style solution, but was worried about cases like `x="2018-01-31"` where 31 days later would jump to March.